# xslt: trying to understand conditional inside value-of

Tags: xslt

I'm expecting only Hola to appear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="helloworld.xslt"?>
<greetings>
  <greeting id="1">
    Hello World!
  </greeting>
  <greeting id="2">
    Hola!
  </greeting>
</greetings>
```

However, both greetings appear.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="greetings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="@id[.>1]"/>
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so much the conditional that is causing a problem, but the fact your statement is selecting the attribute, and so the `xsl:value-of` will output the attribute (but only if the value is greater than 1)

What you need to do is move the conditional to your `xsl:apply-templates`, and then do `<xsl:value-of select="." />` to get your "Hola" value

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="greetings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting[@id > 1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```